# How to Synchronize data fetched from GraphQL with SQLite in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, graphql, amazon-dynamodb

I am using GraphQL to synchronize data in aws dynamoDB using AppSync .

but now I need to store the data that I got from the GraphQL API

here is the code I used using GraphQL :

```
amazonAppSyncClient = new AmazonAppSyncClient ("ACCESS_KEY_ID", "SECRET_ACCESS_KEY", REGION);
graphQLClient = new GraphQLClient ("https://6vl6q5h2c5bxrbmlimiia5hldy.appsync-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/graphql",
    new GraphQLClientOptions {
        HttpMessageHandler = new AWS4SignerMessageHandler (
            amazonAppSyncClient,
            "ACCESS_KEY_ID",
            "SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")
    });

public async Task<List<Book>> GetAllBooks () {
    var graphQLResponse = await graphQLClient.PostQueryAsync (@"query getBooks {
      listBooks {
      items {
      Id
      Title
      ISBN
      Price
      PageCount
      Author}}}");

    var json = graphQLResponse.Data;
    var value = json.GetValue ("listBooks").GetValue ("items");
    List<Book> books = value.ToObject<List<Book>> ();
    return books;
}
```

I used this code from here : https://gist.github.com/NeilBostrom/cab8b9275e39bb90ecf8e06ab980664b

How can I synchronize the returned data locally in SQLite or any offline database ?